# .NET Maui Blazor App not working on Physical Devices

Tags: android, .net, maui-blazor

I have created a .NET Maui Blazor app that was working fine on all Android simulators and physical devices until yesterday. The issue is that when I try to run the app through the debugger in Visual Studio clicking the links to navigate to different pages doesn't work, the app is responsive (meaning, I can scroll on the main page) just can't navigate anywhere. This seems to only be happening on the Samsung galaxy physical device, the app works fine in several simulators, and on iPhone devices. I have uninstalled the app, run shell commands (i.e. adb shell pm clear ) to delete shared preferences, I even reverted my code back to several weeks ago (known working code on the devices) and nothing seems to work. I can't get the app to function as it should on these physical devices. The strange things is this just started happening yesterday, I didn't run anything through the debugger, I opened the app and it wouldn't work correctly. that is when I tried deploying a new version through the debugger and that didn't work, I tried a second Samsung galaxy device (Galaxy S8) and that had the same problem. Has anyone experienced this before? I have a dump from the console when debugging on the device (I had to remove some of the debugger lines because the dump was too many characters):

```
Forwarding debugger port 8840
Detecting existing process
> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>/crc64b5ae0e19d72601fe.MainActivity"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>/crc64b5ae0e19d72601fe.MainActivity }
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives(System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32)' to /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:124 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointSendToIde(System.String)' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:419 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointCheckpoint()' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:414 [0x00000].
[Zygote] isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
[Zygote] accessInfo : 1
[design.techbas] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
[design.techbas] The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
[debug-app-helper] Checking if libmonodroid was unpacked to /data/app/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>-pYfe8ENmnogJsxJD80Z5SQ==/lib/arm64/libmonodroid.so
[debug-app-helper] Native libs extracted to /data/app/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>-pYfe8ENmnogJsxJD80Z5SQ==/lib/arm64, assuming application/android:extractNativeLibs == true
[debug-app-helper] Setting up for DSO lookup in app data directories
[debug-app-helper] Added filesystem DSO lookup location: /data/app/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>-pYfe8ENmnogJsxJD80Z5SQ==/lib/arm64
[debug-app-helper] Using runtime path: /data/app/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>-pYfe8ENmnogJsxJD80Z5SQ==/lib/arm64
[debug-app-helper] checking directory: `/data/user/0/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>/files/.__override__/lib`
[debug-app-helper] directory does not exist: `/data/user/0/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>/files/.__override__/lib`
[debug-app-helper] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/user/0/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[debug-app-helper] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/app/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>-pYfe8ENmnogJsxJD80Z5SQ==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[debug-app-helper] Mono runtime found at: /data/app/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>-pYfe8ENmnogJsxJD80Z5SQ==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[design.techbas] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[DOTNET] JNI_OnLoad: JNI_OnLoad in pal_jni.c
[DOTNET] GetOptionalMethod: optional method setApplicationProtocols ([Ljava/lang/String;)V was not found
[DOTNET] GetOptionalMethod: optional method getApplicationProtocol ()Ljava/lang/String; was not found
[monodroid] Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>/files/.__override__`
[design.techbas] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8840,server=y,embedding=1
[TcpOptimizer] TcpOptimizer-ON
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly <appnamewashere>.dll
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46080
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Mono.Android.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Java.Interop.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Threading.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Threading.Thread.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
[design.techbas] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly netstandard.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Linq.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Json.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
[design.techbas] Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<Cy2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/PacProcessor;
[design.techbas]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
[design.techbas]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
[design.techbas]   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:176)
[design.techbas]   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:459)
[design.techbas]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:251)
[design.techbas]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2681)
[design.techbas]   at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2676)
[design.techbas]   at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2741)
[design.techbas]   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:5190)
[design.techbas]   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:5390)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceEnd(J)V (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
[cr_WVCFactoryProvider] Loaded version=105.0.5195.79 minSdkVersion=24 isBundle=true multiprocess=true packageId=2
[cr_LibraryLoader] Successfully loaded native library
[cr_CachingUmaRecorder] Flushed 8 samples from 8 histograms.
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/Context;->bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handler;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
[ConnectivityManager] requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10258, CallingPid : 12114
[ConnectivityManager] requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10258, CallingPid : 12114
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Xml.XDocument.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (light greylist, reflection)
[cr_media] Requires BLUETOOTH permission
[Adreno] QUALCOMM build                   : 417d66a, I9f2c4682a2
[Adreno] Build Date                       : 12/09/19
[Adreno] OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
[Adreno] Local Branch                     : 
[Adreno] Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.4.R1.09.00.00.453.036
[Adreno] Remote Branch                    : NONE
[Adreno] Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
[Adreno] Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
[vndksupport] Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
[Adreno] PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
[ConfigStore] android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
[ConfigStore] android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;->mAccessibilityDelegate:Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, reflection)
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll
[DecorView] createDecorCaptionView >> DecorView@7033324[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics.Android.Bindings.dll
[ConnectivityManager] requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10258, CallingPid : 12114
[AppCenter] Unable to get installID from Shared Preferences
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Console.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Security.SecurityCrypto.dll
[OpenGLRenderer] Skia GL Pipeline
[EmergencyMode] [EmergencyManager] android createPackageContext successful
[InputTransport] Input channel constructed: fd=157
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] setView = DecorView@7033324[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
[Choreographer] Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] dispatchAttachedToWindow
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 520568233984} changed=true
[OpenGLRenderer] Initialized EGL, version 1.4
[OpenGLRenderer] Swap behavior 2
[OpenGLRenderer] eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7922e40580, 0x793448e010
[AndroidKeysetManager] keyset not found, will generate a new one
[AndroidKeysetManager] java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't read keyset; the pref value __androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset__ does not exist
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.SharedPrefKeysetReader.readPref(SharedPrefKeysetReader.java:71)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.SharedPrefKeysetReader.readEncrypted(SharedPrefKeysetReader.java:89)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.KeysetHandle.read(KeysetHandle.java:116)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.read(AndroidKeysetManager.java:311)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.readOrGenerateNewKeyset(AndroidKeysetManager.java:287)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.build(AndroidKeysetManager.java:238)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:155)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:120)
[vndksupport] Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
[vndksupport] Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
[AndroidKeysetManager] keyset not found, will generate a new one
[AndroidKeysetManager] java.io.FileNotFoundException: can't read keyset; the pref value __androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_value_keyset__ does not exist
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.SharedPrefKeysetReader.readPref(SharedPrefKeysetReader.java:71)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.SharedPrefKeysetReader.readEncrypted(SharedPrefKeysetReader.java:89)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.KeysetHandle.read(KeysetHandle.java:116)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.read(AndroidKeysetManager.java:311)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.readOrGenerateNewKeyset(AndroidKeysetManager.java:287)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.build(AndroidKeysetManager.java:238)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:160)
[AndroidKeysetManager]  at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:120)
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 192) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 192) or=1
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
[InputMethodManager] prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@7033324[MainActivity]
[InputMethodManager] getNavigationBarColor() -855310
[InputMethodManager] prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@7033324[MainActivity]
[InputMethodManager] getNavigationBarColor() -855310
[InputMethodManager] Starting input: tba=com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere> ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
[InputMethodManager] startInputInner - Id : 0
[InputMethodManager] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
[InputTransport] Input channel constructed: fd=170
[InputMethodManager] prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@7033324[MainActivity]
[InputMethodManager] getNavigationBarColor() -855310
[InputMethodManager] Starting input: tba=com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere> ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
[InputMethodManager] startInputInner - Id : 0
[EngineFactory] Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not available
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceCounter(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
[design.techbas] Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[monodroid-assembly] Shared library 'liblog' not loaded, p/invoke '__android_log_print' may fail
[DOTNET] Checking Last Data Update
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Linq.Expressions.dll
[DOTNET] Data Check Finished: 00:00:00.0464618
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Newtonsoft.Json.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Net.Requests.dll
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.IO.Compression.dll
[design.techbas] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 11370(681KB) AllocSpace objects, 44(5MB) LOS objects, 64% free, 3MB/9MB, paused 71us total 22.801ms
[Choreographer] Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[DOTNET] Getting Session Data
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Data.Common.dll
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[DOTNET] Get Session Data Finished: 00:00:01.8730367
[Choreographer] Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[DOTNET] Save Session Data Finished: 00:00:04.7900294
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 0
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[DOTNET] Get Speaker Data Finished: 00:00:05.1415198
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 1
[InputMethodManager] prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@7033324[MainActivity]
[InputMethodManager] getNavigationBarColor() -855310
[InputMethodManager] Starting input: tba=com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere> ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
[InputMethodManager] startInputInner - Id : 0
[InputMethodManager] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
[InputTransport] Input channel constructed: fd=194
[InputTransport] Input channel destroyed: fd=170
[InputMethodManager] HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 12114
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 0
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 1
[InputMethodManager] HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 12114
[design.techbas] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 11416(661KB) AllocSpace objects, 22(2MB) LOS objects, 63% free, 3MB/9MB, paused 63us total 25.279ms
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 0
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 1
[InputMethodManager] HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 12114
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 0
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 1
[InputMethodManager] HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 12114
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 0
[ViewRootImpl@511e45a[MainActivity]] ViewPostIme pointer 1
[InputMethodManager] HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 12114
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[chatty] uid=10258(com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>) .NET ThreadPool identical 2 lines
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[chatty] uid=10258(com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>) .NET ThreadPool identical 2 lines
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[chatty] uid=10258(com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>) .NET ThreadPool identical 2 lines
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[chatty] uid=10258(com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>) .NET ThreadPool identical 2 lines
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[chatty] uid=10258(com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>) .NET ThreadPool identical 2 lines
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[chatty] uid=10258(com.<companynamewashere>.<appnamewashere>) .NET ThreadPool identical 2 lines
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #21
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

I did notice the following message from the debugger "[System.out] (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false" which I do not recall seeing before and I do not see when I run the app in the simulators. I have searched for this and only found old posts, and none of them were helpful for this issue, mentioned above I have already tried deleting shared preferences, that didn't work. I am at a loss, any help would be greatly appricated.

Comment: Is there just a problem with this machine (Samsung galaxy device (Galaxy S8)) ?

Comment: No, the device itself is working fine, I also have a Galaxy S21 and it's the same exact issue,  I have a feeling it may be related to a NuGet package, I am going to roll back the packages and see if that changes anything (I am not convinced it's that). I had a version of the app in the Google Play Console for internal testing, which I know was working, I uninstalled the app from both phones and installed the version from Google Play, and it is the same issue. I will see what happens tonight when I try to rollback the NuGet Packages and post any updates.

Comment: Update: this is not a fix, but interesting enough I thought I should share it. After trying everything from removing all NuGet packages to rebuilding an old commit of the app from scratch with no luck. I did a factory reset on one of the Samsung devices (it's a test device) and deployed the app, it works perfectly, no issues.

My next step is going to be building the app from scratch and slowly adding the code back in to see if any issue pop up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be related to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9882, try latest android webview 105.0.5195.136,
also the apps will run again if you refresh the page, can try debug from chrome inspect chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: That seems to be the issue. Uninstalling the latest version of the Android System WebView fixed it, The app started working as soon as I uninstalled the latest update. I will post any updates after google makes updates to the Android System WebView. Thank you Xavier, that post you shared and your help did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue. I've tested with several devices (Samsung, OnePlus, Oppo) and they all have the same result. All emulators tested do work fine, as well as the windows version app.

[Edit]
I don't think the accepted answer below is actually a solution. You can't just ask random users to uninstall a specific version of a web view

Comment: That was the only fix at the time. Google has since updated the System WebView which can be downloaded here (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)